# Rails - Create internal server error (500) at localhost

Tags: ruby-on-rails, error-handling, localhost

I couldn't see 500 error when I accessed a URL for which there is no Data, rather it was showing the 'Template missing' error. At the same time, when I ran it at the server, it had shown the 500 error. I need to do testing at local machine. So please tell me how I can create such a situation at localhost?

Thanks & Regards,
Rajesh

Comment: Firstly, accept some answers. Secondly, you're looking for a 404 not a 500 error.

Comment: @Bongs, Simpleton : How can I accept the answers? Is it by voting up the answer? If yes, I should have a reputation above 15 which i have not. I am a beginner, so kindly co-operate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create such situation in localhost if you run the server in production mode: `rails s -e production` (Of course, if the error is still present)

Answer (score 1):

If you are getting a template missing error is most probably because you are missing the view file for a given controller action

Ex: if you have a controller called users

```
class UsersController < ApplicatationController

   def index
   end

end
```

by default rails is expecting a view in

`app/views/users/index.html.erb` (or haml)

But if you could post the error log you are getting we might be able to help you more

regards

sameera

Comment: 'http://0.0.0.0:3000/-avesani-3ygcc-55dsl-sunglasses_r9' is the localhost URL for which we are getting the template missing error. This URL is to show a particular product's features and we are redirected to this URL when we click the same product from the product listing. If we change something in the URL and hit enter we are getting Template missing error. But in the production domain, i.e. at the sever, the URL corresponding to the same product showing 500 error. I need to create it at localhost. I will show you the template error shown. Please assist me.

Comment: Template is missing

Missing template pages/-avesani-3ygcc-55dsl-sunglasses_r1 with {:formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:rjs, :rhtml, :haml, :rxml, :erb, :builder], :locale=>[:en, :en]} in view paths "/home/rajesh/www/shoppingsaver/Source/app/views", "/home/rajesh/www/shoppingsaver/Source/vendor/plugins/tabnav/app/views", "/home/rajesh/www/shoppingsaver/Source/vendor/plugins/recaptcha/app/views", "/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/kaminari-0.12.4/app/views", "/home/rajesh/www/shoppingsaver/Source", "/"

Comment: hi @rajesh , can u provide the controller method also to get an Idea on how u getting the product details (appears to be that this is a product name) and normally in a case like this we pass the product name and it renders a partial with details, BTW are u sure your product name is correct? (-avesani-3ygcc-55dsl-sunglasses_r1) coz its little strange to have a - in the begining  :)

Comment: OK, try running the localhost in production mode ruby script/server -e production (or rails s in Rails3) and see if it works same as in server, because the default localhost runs in development mode and server is most probably running in the production mode

Answer (score 1):

It's a simple problem with your corresponding view not being present. Open the control file which corresponds to your url. Then see the action which is being called and then, see if the corresponding view is available in the app/views/ folder.

The reason for 500 error is the same 500 says that there was an internal error at the server side.

Also, don't go about changing the url's charecter and stuff. IT WONT WORK!

Comment: Hi Unsung, I appreciate your feedback. But, For the same code base and the product URL,the production server returns 500 error by displaying the layout we created for the 500 error(As the product not present in server Database). Why it is not happening at localhost??

Comment: It might be an exception handling scenario. Your controller might be throwing an exception or might be throwing an error which is not handled in the code. You need to verify how the scenario for the product not being in database is handled at the code level. I have a nagging doubt that the problem is with the way it has been handled.